# phpMyAdmin – creating procedure with multiple lines of code

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create procedure in phpMyAdmin.
I am always getting error. I tried the easiest example with two selects:

```
select * from xxx_hikashop_product;
select * from xxx_hikashop_price;
```

But it shows me always error on second line. If I use commants separately, so the procedure has only one line, it works.

**Where is the problem please? Why I cannot write more lines of code?**

Thank you,
Filip

Comment: "An error"? What error? Please, *be specific*.

Comment: Multiple statements in a procedure need to be wrapped in a begin end statement